# How to force request to contain all the attributes in Spring?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class RetailerPincodeMapping {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Indexed
    private Long retailerId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Indexed
    private Integer pincode;

    private boolean active;

    @NotEmpty
    private String deliveryMode;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedAt;

}
```

Currently have a class defined like this. 
An ideal request would be :

```
{
        "retailerId": 239,
        "pincode": 40061,
        "deliveryMode": "COURIER",
        "active": true
}
```

Suppose if explicitly set retailerId as null or any other value which cannot be parsed as Long, I get an error (desired behaviour) but if I skip the attribute altogether in the request than it takes it as null (undesired)

```
{
        "retailerId" : null //Throws error (desired)
        "pincode": 40061,
        "deliveryMode": "COURIER",
        "active": true
}
```

```
{
        "pincode": 40061, // Doesn't throw an error (Undesired)
        "deliveryMode": "COURIER",
        "active": true
}
```

How can I avoid this? 
I want the request to fail if all the required attributes are not present in it.

Comment: Did you try spring validator ?

Comment: `@NotEmpty` allows `null` add an additional `@NotNull`.

Comment: @M.Deinum That did not solve the issue

Comment: What doesn't work? It should, did you use the proper `@NotNull` annotation AND do you have a valid validation implementation like hibernate-validator on your classpath (without it the annotations don't do anything!).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're talking here about the deserialization here. Did you try to use `@JsonInclude` annotation? You could also use your custom deserializer: 
`@JsonDeserialize`. Do you have `@Valid` annotation on your parameter in the controller layer?

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum answered, you need additional validation for not null fields. You should use @NotNull:

```
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Indexed
private Long retailerId;
```

JFY, comparison of different validation rules:

```
String name = null;  
@NotNull = false  
@NotEmpty = false  
@NotBlank = false  

String nam = "";  
@NotNull = true  
@NotEmpty = false  
@NotBlank = false  

String name = "  ";  
@NotNull = true  
@NotEmpty = true  
@NotBlank = false  

String name = "string"  
@NotNull = true  
@NotEmpty = true  
@NotBlank = true
```

Comment: @GVSandeep, I think something is missed in your validation configuration. Provide your controller implementation